# prevent string input in datepicker in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

How can I prevent the textbox of `Datepicker` to accept string as input or invalid date as input?

I have tried by adding `AddError()` at `DateValidationError` event of `Datepicker`, but it's not working for me.

Comment: You want to prevent or enable? first line says you want to accept string, 2nd line says you want to add a validation if its a string.Please be clear

Answer (score 0):

You may register on `TextChanged` event of the `DatePickerTextBox` and restore the previous value if you cannot parse the input. **Note** that this would disable common editing scenarios where the date string is inserted char by char.

You should clarify your question and say whether you want invalid text to be rejected or rather trigger an error provider.